# django date by month only filter validation err

Tags: django

I need a date filter that selects month only. But it gives "Enter a valid date" error when filter is applied. How to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

filters.py

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.DateFilter(
        field_name='date',
        lookup_expr='exact',  # You can change the lookup expression if needed
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'month'})
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'date']
```

template

```
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" name="order_filter" value="Apply"/>
</form>
```

views.py

```
filter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=Order.objects.filter(status=True))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can not filter with a `DateFilter` and the corresponding widget, since it is not a month. But even if that widget would work, it would only filter perhaps in the first of the month.

The first thing we should do is make a `MonthFilter` with:

```
class MonthFilter(Filter):
    field_class = MonthField

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value is not None:
            return qs.filter(
                **{
                    f'{self.field_name}__year': value.year,
                    f'{self.field_name}__month': value.month,
                }
            )
        return qs
```

then the `MonthField` will need to pass us a `datetime` with the first of that month, so:

```
from django.forms import DateField


class MonthField(DateField):
    widget = MonthInput
    input_formats = ['%Y-%m']
```

Finally we define a `MonthInput` widget that will format the value to a month:

```
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput


class MonthInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'month'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('format', '%Y-%m')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then we can filter with our custom-made `MonthFilter`:

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = MonthFilter(field_name='date')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'date']
```

The `MonthFilter` can further be implemented. For example it will not work with `lookup_expr='gt'` since it does not take the `lookup_expr` into account, and therefore is only limited to a full month match.